# When modifiers applied, sculpting doesn't work correctly

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

I have made a mesh with mirror- and subsurface modifiers but when I apply them and switch to sculpt mode, it says "the object has non-uniform scale, sculpting may be unpredictable".

[image]

When I try to sculpt, the result is with any sculpting tool this:

[image]

Sculpting works with any object/mesh but this and if I try to recreate it with the same methods as this one, it does the same thing.

Comment: Apply Scale with Ctrl A in object mode.

Comment: It should have provided you with this message even before you had applied the modifier and the modifier has nothing to do with that